# Java EOFException when using BMPImageReader after performing RLE compression on Byte Array

Tags: java, image-processing, exception, image-compression, run-length-encoding

I'm getting an `EOFException` when trying to compress a `Bitmap` image using RLE. I basically take a bytearray of a bitmap image, then perform RLE compression on everything after the 54th Byte since that is all Header File stuff.
I then use `BMPImageReader` to read in the new Byte Array and then `BMPImageWriter` to save it as a new RLE8 compressed bitmap.

However in the section

```
        File file = new File("runLength.txt");
        ... 
        BMPImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = new BMPImageWriteParam();
        imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(2);
        imageWriteParam.setCompressionType("BI_RLE8");
        imageWriteParam.setTopDown(true);
        BMPImageWriter bmpImageWriter = (BMPImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("bmp").next();                   
        FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);            
        bmpImageWriter.setOutput(output);            


        BMPImageReader bmpImageReader = (BMPImageReader) ImageIO.getImageReader(bmpImageWriter);
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bais);
        bmpImageReader.setInput(iis);
        ImageReadParam param = bmpImageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
        imageRLE = bmpImageReader.read(0, param);
```

it throws the exception on the last line. I've stepped through the code and it gets passed the header fine but then throws the exception when reading the first byte (I think ... it is kind of difficult to follow).

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.io.EOFException
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:353)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.read24Bit(BMPImageReader.java:1227)
at com.sun.imageio.plugins.bmp.BMPImageReader.read(BMPImageReader.java:882)
at cs24010.RLECompression.stringToImage(RLECompression.java:139)
at cs24010.RLECompression.compress(RLECompression.java:63)
at cs24010.RLECompression.run(RLECompression.java:219)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the error?

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to do here, but going run length encoding by hand on a byte-array seems the wrong approach ... no matter what you are trying to do.  Surely the BMPImageWriter is going to take care of that ...

Comment: Nope not how it works, you have to have an RLE compressed bitmap image before you can write the new image in RLE8... So I have to compress it manually first and then write it in RLE8, that way what ever image viewer is being used knows that the image is RLE8 compressed and knows to decode it before reading it

Comment: I have been thinking that I might have to go a different route and instead unpack the pixels of the bitmap and then compress it... But that's just so complicated

Comment: Your "that's not how it works" does not make sense to me.  But either way, the EOFException is strongly suggestive that you are reading what is in effect a malformed BMP file from the byte array.